# convert 8-bit unsigned integer to/from float on Intel Knights Corner (KNC, Xeon Phi Gen 1)

Tags: c, type-conversion, intrinsics, xeon-phi, avx512

I'm making a program for the Knights Corner (KNC) cpu to execute. It seems to have a prototype of AVX512 as its instruction set, but I could find no indication on the Intel Intrinsic Guide for conversion between various integer widths.

Specifically, I'm trying to convert 8-bit integers (unsigned) into 32-bit integers so I can operate on them with KNC. How can I do this on KNC? Is there some equivalent to AVX512-F's `_mm512_cvtepu8_epi32()` to go from 8-bit to 32-bit and `_mm512_cvtu[s]epi32_epi8()` to go from 32-bit back to 8-bit?

Comment: Please remove KNL from your title. You are not asking about KNL (Knights Landing),  but (as you make clear elsewhere) Knights Corner (KNC).